# Не могу подключиться к Ораклу из VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net, visual-studio-2017

Пишу под ASP.NET MVC Framework веб-сервис, который должен работать с СУБД Oracle. Установлен Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017.
Проблема: VS в упор не видит oracle, если выполнить *Средства - Подключиться к БД - БД Oracle* вываливается ошибка.

СУБД - Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.
(Пытался установить коннект через entity framework, подключил все необходимые библиотеки, тоже тщетно: при попытке создать модель ADO.NET EDM, в качестве источника данных VS предлагает использовать MS SQL Server, Oracle в списке нет)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установите oracle клиент, раз просит.

Comment: клиент oracle установлен

Comment: битность клиента?

Comment: SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0

Comment: КМК, SQL*Plus -- интерпретатор команд для СУБД (сервер); клиент оракл это просто набор доп.файлов(DLL и пр.), необходимых вашему приложению для обращения к БД.
Установка клиента -- [скачать с оф.сайта](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) файлы клиента Оракл (они хотят регистрацию =( ), распаковать в папку с исполняемым приложения / проектом.    

PS: не ответом, потому что я сам не писал никогда под ASP.NET MVC Framework, может тут своя _внутренняя_ _кухня_.

Comment: "клиент oracle установлен" - но не находится, значит установлен не правильно. Какой клиент установлен? Как установлен?